# JAX-RS How to get a cookie from a request?

Tags: java, rest, service, jax-rs

Consider the following method:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
public SearchResponse doSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest);
```

I would like this method to be aware of the user who made the request. As such, I need access to the cookie associated with the `SearchRequest` object sent from the user.

In the SearchRequest class I have only this implementation:

```
public class SearchRequest {

      private String ipAddress;
      private String message;
...
```

And here is the request:

```
{
  "ipAddress":"0.0.0.0",
  "message":"foobarfoobar"
}
```

Along with this request, the browser sends the cookie set when the user signed into the system.

My question is how to access the cookie in the context of the `doSearch` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `javax.ws.rs.CookieParam` annotation on an argument of your method.

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
public SearchResponse doSearch( 
   SearchRequest searchRequest, 
   @CookieParam("cookieName") Cookie cookie
) {
    //method body
}
```

The `Cookie` class used here is `javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie` but you don't have to use it.

You can use this annotation on any argument as long as is:

1. is a primitive type
2. is a `Cookie` (same as in the example above)
3. has a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument
4. has a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
5. havs a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
6. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2, 3, 4 or 5 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

These rules come from the [documentation of the `@CookieParam` annotation as implemented in Jersey, the reference implementation of JAX-RS](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html)

Comment: How should the json looks ?                                              {
  "ipAddress":"0.0.0.0",
  "message":"foobarfoobar",                                            
  "Cookie" ...............? -- I expect the browser to return the Cookie by default so I guess this parameter will be automatically filled by the browser ?
}

Comment: The JSON does not have to change. Cookies are not stored in the request body. To set cookies, you should use HTTP headers. How are you calling the service? Are you using a JAX-RS Java client library? Are you calling it from a JavaScript frontend?

Comment: Yes, the requests I do by JavaScript.

Comment: I did it, thanks. It is working. The Cookie parameter is auto filled from the browser as I was expecting. Thanks Tom !